# Eclipse error in project properties

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have Eclipse installed on my Antergos (Archlinux-based) operating system and I wanted to change settings in the C/C++ build of my project but when I try to open that I get the following error:

[image: Eclipse Project Properties Error].

This error is followed by a Java exception (NullPointerException).

I tried updating the Eclipse but it is already up to date. I also tried to restart the application and clean/build but to no avail.
Until today I never had such a problem with it. I thought maybe it is a new update but I couldn't find someone else who had experienced the same problem.

What does this error mean and how to fix it?

EDIT:Here are the contents of the .log file:

```
!SESSION 2016-04-15 12:12:33.269 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.5.2.M20160212-1500
java.version=1.8.0_77
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.cdt.core 1 0 2016-04-15 12:13:22.347
!MESSAGE Indexed 'DS1' (1 sources, 123 headers) in 3.77 sec: 9,277 declarations; 16,255 references; 0 unresolved inclusions; 0 syntax errors; 0 unresolved names (0%)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 2 2016-04-15 12:14:11.756
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TabFolder.gtk_switch_page(TabFolder.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.windowProc(Widget.java:2009)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4723)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS._gtk_widget_show(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.gtk_widget_show(OS.java:14774)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TabFolder.createItem(TabFolder.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TabItem.createWidget(TabItem.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TabItem.<init>(TabItem.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.ui.newui.AbstractPage$InternalTab.createOn(AbstractPage.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.ui.newui.AbstractPage.loadTab(AbstractPage.java:1147)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.ui.newui.AbstractPage.loadExtensionsSynchronized(AbstractPage.java:1092)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.ui.newui.AbstractPage.createWidgets(AbstractPage.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.ui.newui.AbstractPage.contentForCDT(AbstractPage.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.ui.newui.AbstractPage.createContents(AbstractPage.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferencePage.createControl(PreferencePage.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.createPageControl(PreferenceDialog.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$13.run(PreferenceDialog.java:1217)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.showPage(PreferenceDialog.java:1209)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.FilteredPreferenceDialog.showPage(FilteredPreferenceDialog.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$9$1.run(PreferenceDialog.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$9.selectionChanged(PreferenceDialog.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$3.run(StructuredViewer.java:877)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.firePostSelectionChanged(StructuredViewer.java:874)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handlePostSelect(StructuredViewer.java:1243)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$5.widgetSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1269)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.firePostSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$5(OpenStrategy.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1$2.run(OpenStrategy.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3794)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3433)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:827)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.PropertyDialogAction.run(PropertyDialogAction.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4481)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1329)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3819)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3430)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:694)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)
```

Comment: It means that there is a bug in the code for that property page. Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message. If there is edit your question to add the details from the .log.

Comment: I have the same problem I guess. Using ArchLinux and the current version from eclipse.org,  I can't access the Java Build Path Option. My stack trace can be found here http://pastebin.com/N0dWfpn8

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been reported here :

https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/commit/?id=1a375bfbb7dca92b102db09891a18eeb80d671f2

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=486069

I think Archlinux users seems to be the first to see it due to the fact Arch packages are always at the latest version available and have recently updated Gtk and Wayland libraries.